# Physics applications of quantum logic

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

Are there any examples of quantum logic being applied to solve actual physical questions, in particular to predict the physical properties (spectrum etc.) of some quantum-mechanical system? (Note that I'm not considering applications in quantum computing here.)

EDIT: To clarify what I mean, consider a simple system like the harmonic oscillator. Using real variables $q_t$ and $p_t$ indexed by real-valued time $t$, and starting from energy conservation in a form like $\forall t\forall s p_s\cdot p_s+\omega\cdot\omega\cdot q_s\cdot q_s=p_t\cdot p_t+\omega\cdot\omega\cdot q_t\cdot q_t$ and from the relation $\dot{q}=p$ expressed using a form "$\forall\epsilon\ldots<\epsilon$", I have no doubt that most of the properties of the classical system could be laboriously derived using the axioms for the real numbers and classical logic. (Of course if I'm wrong and there is some obstacle that means that solving even such a simple dynamical system cannot be logically formalized, that would be an interesting answer, too!) Has anyone ever tried to derive the properties of the corresponding quantum system using some appropriate form of quantum logic?

Comment: What do you mean by "quantum logic"? If you just mean the rules of quantum mechanics, you better use those if you want to correctly treat any quantum mechanical system.

Comment: quantum computing is not a part of physics? it exploits the laws of physics, doesn't it?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: So does classical computing ... but you're right, I could have phrased that better.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt: I always took "quantum logic" to be a well-defined term for propositional logics built on non-distributive lattices.

Comment: Yes, and no. Until you try to solve some of the problems and find out for yourself, you don't know the answer. :P

Comment: @gmvh, how would you respond to the corresponding question: Are there any examples of classical logic being applied to solve actual physical questions? If the answers all look awkward, then the question is probably awkward too.

Comment: @MattF., fair point, but quantum logic takes its inspiration from quantum physics, so some special applicability would not be a particular surprise.

Comment: Many things take inspiration from quantum physics, as Alan Sokal showed, so I wouldn't expect too much on that basis....but I think you'd get an interesting question if you ask it in such a way that both the classical and quantum versions have reasonable answers.

Comment: FYI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm fairly confident that there are no such derivations, and for good reason.

The paper I like on this topic is by Michael Dunn, [Quantum Mathematics](https://philpapers.org/rec/DUNQM). He concludes

> First-order Peano arithmetic formulated with quantum logic has the
>   same theorems as classical first-order Peano arithmetic. Distribution
>   for first-order arithmetical formulas is a theorem not of quantum
>   logic but rather of arithmetic.

He also gets a similar result for extensional second-order arithmetic.

So if the energy conservation is formalized in any Dunn-like extensional system, it will have the same consequences using either classical logic or quantum logic.

Getting different results from quantum logic would be a tall order -- especially since quantum logic is a subsystem of classical logic. This would presumably require:

- 1) A decision to model the physical system using some axiomatics which are consistent under quantum logic but inconsistent under classical logic.
- 2) A formalized treatment of real numbers and functions under quantum logic, sufficiently advanced to allow discussion of derivatives, which does not give the same theorems as classical mathematics.

Success might look like a quantum analog of synthetic differential geometry, which uses intuitionist logic. This is indeed sufficiently advanced to allow discussion of derivatives, inconsistent with classical logic (violating $\forall x  (x=0 \vee x\neq 0)$), and giving different theorems from classical mathematics (e.g. $\forall x(\forall y(y^2=0 \rightarrow xy=0)\rightarrow x=0$).

I've tried my hand at finding that quantum treatment of real numbers and functions, without success, and so far as I can tell no one else has had success either.

Comment: Wow, you really didn't promise too much when you said there could be an interesting answer if the question is posed right. This is amazing, thanks a lot!